# How can I size table nodes in graphviz that contain bold text?

Tags: graphviz

I'm rendering a pipeline diagram with graphviz. Each node is a step in the pipeline and uses a table for layout. The top row is in bold and shows the name of the step. The other rows show the outputs of the step. Arrows between steps show dependencies.

```
digraph {
  node[shape=plaintext]

  A [
    label=<
      <table border="1" cellborder="0" cellspacing="1" >
      <tr><td align="left"><b>FirstVeryLongVeryBoldStepName</b></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="left">→ out.txt</td></tr>
      </table>
    >];

  B [
    label=<
      <table border="1" cellborder="0" cellspacing="1" >
      <tr><td align="left"><b>SecondVeryLongVeryBoldStepName</b></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="left">→ out2.txt</td></tr>
      <tr><td align="left">→ out3.json</td></tr>
      </table>
    >];

  A -> B
}
```

Here's how it renders:

[image: pipeline]

The width of each box seems to be set based on the non-bold width of the text. If I remove the `<b>` tag, the layout looks just right:

[image: pipeline with tight layout]

How can I get the tight layout with the bold text? If it's helpful, here's a [link to the example in Graphviz Online](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%5Bshape%3Dplaintext%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20cellspacing%3D%221%22%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%3Cb%3EFirstVeryLongVeryBoldStepName%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%E2%86%92%20out.txt%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20B%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20cellspacing%3D%221%22%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%3Cb%3ESecondVeryLongVeryBoldStepName%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%E2%86%92%20out2.txt%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%E2%86%92%20out3.json%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20A%20-%3E%20B%0A%0A%20%20%7D)

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting, that on on my machine your code renders fine (on both Mac with graphviz 2.41 and Ubundtu with graphviz 2.40: [rendered.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EySDq.jpg)). Maybe it depends on the font engine used during graphviz build.

In your situation you may just add three spaces at the end of each bold text node: [link to fixed example](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%5Bshape%3Dplaintext%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20cellspacing%3D%221%22%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%3Cb%3EFirstVeryLongVeryBoldStepName%20%20%20%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%E2%86%92%20out.txt%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20B%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20cellspacing%3D%221%22%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%3Cb%3ESecondVeryLongVeryBoldStepName%20%20%20%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%E2%86%92%20out2.txt%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%E2%86%92%20out3.json%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20A%20-%3E%20B%0A%0A%20%20%7D)

If the spaces are being eaten up by HTML parser (may occur especially if you are rendering svg), you can replace them with `&nbsp;` symbol (non-breakable space).

Comment: Presumably the number of spaces depends on the length of the text?

Comment: @danvk right, but empirically I determined that three spaces should be fine for the short and most of the long strings. For extremely long they won't be enough, of course

Comment: too many spaces results in a gap on the right for short labels. It looks like the right number of spaces is about `len(label) / 10`.